# Apple Yosemite root problems

Tags: macos, root, sandbox

I always work as a root user, and I've been facing some problems:

1. Finder never saves passwords.
2. Icon positioning changes aren't saved.
3. Other problems in strong sandbox hardening and I can't load a lot of apps.

I did a full restore of `SYSTEM` three times, then `RESET ACL` and also a reset following some suggestions in the Apple forum, but nothing worked.

Does anybody know how to downgrade hardening or how to fix these problems?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT ;)

Comment: Please consider using better grammar and spellings

Comment: I guess the solution is not to use root as for every *NIX

Comment: thanks
sorry for bad english Quill

It's hard for me to translate tech words as SYSTEM (the system partition of the mac, usually named SYSTEM) and RESET ACL (with other terms, too) 

those terms I think must be properly written un UC not lower case. Don't you agree?

For the user, I always used root since 10yrs for technical reasons .. believe me I know it's dangerous, i'm a technician IT, not a graphic designer.

thanks, in advance

Comment: Maybe this is a semi-obvious question, but: Does it work when you log in as non-root? If it still does not then there is no need to focus on being root user? If it does then lets proceed on 'what the heck are the differences?' (other than uid 0).